# iOS 8 NSNumberFormatter rounding behavior different than in previous versions

Tags: ios, objective-c

Say I have a double with the value 16.5. Under iOS 8 the NSNumberFormatter returns the string as 17.
In previous versions the return value was 16.5.

```
//double value = 16.5
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

NSDictionary *localeData = [staticLocaleData objectForKey:code];
localeData = (localeData ? localeData: [staticLocaleData objectForKey:@"EUR"]);
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:fractionDigits];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMinimumIntegerDigits:1];
formatter.usesSignificantDigits = NO;

NSDictionary *format = [localeData objectForKey:@"format"];
[formatter setDecimalSeparator:[format objectForKey:@"decimalSeparator"]];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:[format objectForKey:@"thousendSeparator"]];

NSString *retStr = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(value)]; // iOS 6 + 7: 16.5     iOS 8: 17
[formatter release];
```

Commenting out the line with NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp didn't show any difference.

Comment: What is fractionDigits set to?

Comment: Updated above with solution: formatter.usesSignificantDigits = NO;

Comment: I am also have these issues, my numberfomatter keeps returning incorrect values, seems to only be present on the iOS8 runtime.